# Unable to find CheckBox inside a nested repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a nested repeater and a check box inside that, Like this

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptInterestCategory" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptInterestCategory_ItemDataBound" >

    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptInterests" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptInterests_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbInterest" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="cbInterest_CheckedChanged" Data-Id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id") %>' Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name") %>' />

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <hr/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And I have button outside this repeater, On this button click event I want to get all the values of that check box. I have tried some thing like this,

```
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem repeated in rptInterestCategory.Items)
        {
            var rptInterests = (Repeater)FindControlRecursive(repeated, "rptInterests");
            foreach (RepeaterItem repeatedInterest in rptInterests.Items)
            {
                var cbInterest = (CheckBox)FindControlRecursive(repeated, "cbInterest");

                if (cbInterest.Checked)
                {
                    name = cbInterest.Text;
                }
            }
        }
}
 public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
    {
        if (root.ID == id)
            return root;

        return root.Controls.Cast<Control>()
            .Select(c => FindControlRecursive(c, id))
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c != null);
    }
```

Now the problem is that,  This code always finds first CheckBox only, So i get repeated values. IS there any way to loop through each check box and find correct values?

Comment: do you want all selected check box value or single value?

Comment: @Shirish all selected checkbox value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call FindControlRecursive in the inner loop with the same parameters as outer loop. That's the problem?

```
var cbInterest = (CheckBox)FindControlRecursive(repeatedInterest , "cbInterest");
```

the full code:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem repeated in rptInterestCategory.Items)
    {
        var rptInterests = (Repeater)FindControlRecursive(repeated, "rptInterests");
        foreach (RepeaterItem repeatedInterest in rptInterests.Items)
        {
            var cbInterest = (CheckBox)FindControlRecursive(repeatedInterest , "cbInterest");

            if (cbInterest.Checked)
            {
                name = cbInterest.Text;
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to define one string  or array of string out side the loop.
 In this answer I am giving solution in one string. In `String s` you will get all checked checkboxes value and separate sign is `^` 
On `button_click` just put my code and you will get all selected `CheckBox` value.

```
string s = "";
            foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptInterestCategory.Items)
            {
                if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
                {
                    Repeater dl = (Repeater)item.FindControl("rptInterests");
                    foreach (RepeaterItem dli in repeatedInterest.Items)
                    {
                        if (dli.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || dli.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
                        {
                            var checkBox = (CheckBox)dli.FindControl("cbInterest");
                            if (checkBox.Checked) { s += (s == "") ? checkBox.Text : "^" + checkBox.Text; }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```